# R For Loop - Increment by 5's but start at 1

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I would think this has come up before, but cant seem to find the answer.

I want to loop from 1:20, by 5. I can do this using:

```
for (i in seq(1,20,5)){

print(i)
}
```

But I would like for my sequencing to go: `1,5,10,15,20`. I know that I can do some manual stuff like the following, but this is way too cumbersome to do repeatedly. Is there some easily built in way of doing this in R?

```
for (i in seq(1,21,5)){

  if (i != 1){
     i <- i-1
  }

  print(i)

}
```

Comment: Try `c(1,  seq(5, 20, by = 5))`

Comment: Strictly speaking, _loop from 1:20, by 5_ is `seq(1, 20, 5);  1  6 11 16`.

Comment: That does work @akrun , not sure why I didnt think of just making a vector like that.

Comment: @EricFail , exactly why I asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to concatenate 1 with the `seq` output

```
c(1, seq(5, 20, by = 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
c(1,seq(5,20,5))
```

Because the difference from 1 to 5 is different from the other steplength, adding 1 maunally is probably best.